# 301 Redirect in htaccess. Matching Page IDs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I would like some help creating an htaccess 301 redirect for the below type of url.

In total there's around 500 or so products but rather than write a redirect for every url, which would be very bulky and time consuming, I'm hoping there's an easier way that I haven't yet found to create a kind of regular expression match?

OLD: http://www.example.co.uk/test-product-name-slug/prod_233.html

NEW: http://www.example.co.uk/test-product-name-slug-233.html

The new URL can be accessed by browsing to ..... example.co.uk/-223.html ...... which then rewrites to ..... example.co.uk/test-product-name-slug-233.html

So it would appear I need a way of detecting if the incoming visitor is coming to a url that cotains prod_id and redirecting to -id

I hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for. It only matches 1 directory in

`/some-product_name-random/prod_9393.html` => `/some-product_name-random-9393.html`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-A-_]+)/prod_([0-9]+)\.html$ /$1-$2.html [R=301,L,QSA]
```

**Regex and Parameters Explained**

`([a-zA-A-_]+)` matches product name `$1`

`prod_([0-9]+)` matches product id `$2`

`[R=301]` 301 permanent redirect

`[L]` stop .htaccess script (may be removed, but usually good practice for specific rules when using multiple rules for different scenarios)

`[QSA]` keep query string `domain.com/somepath/page.html?querystring=value&otherstuff` (`?...`)